# Does django have a user editable templating language that is secure like rails has liquid?

Tags: python, django

Does django have a user editable templating language that is secure like rails has liquid?

i.e. a end user can't hack template code to somehow output dangerous objects and hack the website.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the template language the right way: yes.

See Django template tags and filters:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#escape
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

An example:

```
{{ evil_userinput }}
```

This will print out the users input directly.

```
{{ evil_userinput|escape }}
```

This will escape all HTML entities an so it isn't possible to include dangerous code in your HTML page.

Comment: Not sure if you understand, but the end user will be editing the template sytnax...via a web editor.

Comment: The whole HTML-Page or parts of it?

Comment: Why should the user do that? Does the user only need the HTML code or does he need the full power of an template engine? In principle you can protect. The question is what you want ;-)

Comment: Also - here is a django snippet to whitelist safe template tags for those concerned about security. https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2750/

Answer (score 1):

Liquid has originated from Django templating language, so the answer is yes. You can render user submitted templates and process them the way you want. Security however is something that developers should concern. Templating tools won't protect you if you want to let your users shoot you in the foot unless you sanitize and validate their input.

Here are a few good reads:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09/

http://loopj.com/2009/05/23/a-django-developers-views-on-rails/

Comment: i guess my question is how to not shoot myself in the foot then?